# Iterating through an unknown length array of textareas, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea, loops

I'm trying to iterate through an array of textareas on my page with ClassName `TextInput` and change their values (`innerHTML`). 
The function I wrote is as follows-

```
    function init() {
        var TextInput[] = document.getElementByClassName("TextInput"); //line 12
        for(var i = 0; i < TextInput.length; i++) {
            TextInput[i].innerHTML = "N/A";
        }
    }
```

Firefox 18.0.2's debug console says `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` on line 12.

What is wrong with my code and how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `[]`, just

```
var TextInput = document.getElementByClassName("TextInput"); //line 12
```

Edit: And as @Benjamin pointed out, the function name is missing a `s`.

This should work:

```
var TextInput = document.getElementsByClassName("TextInput"); //line 12
```

Comment: Also, the function name is getElelent**s**ByClassName

Comment: Did it and now it says- `TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function` on line 12.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It worked. `getElementsByClassName` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @SamikSengupta The bug you notices was pointed out by @ Dogbert , I just notices another thing missing . You should accept his answer.